# Linking 2 projects together in Visual Studio 19

Tags: c++, visual-c++, configuration, visual-studio-2019, project

I have 2 projects in 1 solution both projects contain cpp/h files I am trying to have a "Base" project where the "Main" project will contain the files from the "Base".
"Base" configured as Utility project hence does not actually compile anything, of course since it does contain cpp files that even if I use the VS reference tool to link the projects together VS still refuses to compile the cpp files from "Base" hence I get linker errors when trying to compile the solution, one would simply suggest that I reconfigure "Base" to be statically linked however since I would prefer to use different config files (header files) on each "Main" project that I use in the future, static linking is not viable.
Another way of asking is can I have 2 projects that behave like a single project?
I would happy to hear suggestions without using CMake.

Comment: Base is configured as Utility (doesn't produce any output)
Main as DLL

Comment: In fact, if Base does not produce any output, using Base as a lib or dll will be a good choice.

Comment: it would be a good choice if it was possible, since I am using some header files from Main in Base sort of like config files that would differ each Main project while keeping the same Base project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a “Shared Items Project” more info here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cross-platform-code-sharing-with-visual-c/

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.